# Fedora: Citrix ICAClient SSL Error 61

Tags: fedora, rhel, certificates, citrix

Citrix workspace app fails to launch after downloading the .ica file.
The error says:

> SSL Error
> Contact your help desk with the following information:
> You have not chosen to trust "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA", the issuer of the server's security certificate (SSL error 61).

[image]

I was able to easily fix it on Ubuntu (20.04) by linking the certificates:

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

But on Fedora v34 (derived from Redhat) that fix doesn't work. /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla does not exist.

I have also tried linking the files in /etc/ssl/certs to the ICAClient path as well as:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/* /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

Comment: You can download the certificate here: https://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertHighAssuranceEVRootCA.crt.pem and then please have a look at the following: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/using-shared-system-certificates/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your browser goto the site where you launch your citrix session from and click on the padlock widget on far left part of the url

-> click on "Connection is secure"

______   on chrome browser ______

-> click on "Certificate is valid"

this will open a popup window

-> on chrome click on tab "Details"

-> look at the field "Certificate Hierarchy"

-> click on the bottom most line which is the name of your cert

-> hit Export (which will download the cert file)

______   on firefox ______

-> click on "More information"

this will open a popup window get into its "Security" tab

-> click on "View Certificate"

-> this will open a page click on the "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA" tab

-> look at "Miscellaneous" -> Download

-> click on "PEM (cert)" and it will download the cert file

---

> we are done with the browser

rename the cert file you just downloaded so it ends with .pem ... my freshly downloaded file lives at `~/Downloads/foo.bar.pem`

in a terminal issue following commands

```
cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/
sudo mv cacerts  cacerts~~ignore
sudo ln -s /etc/ssl/certs cacerts
sudo cp ~/Downloads/foo.bar.pem  /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts
```

if your box does not have dir `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts` then you can identify your correct path by issuing

```
dpkg -L  icaclient | grep cacerts
```

finally issue

```
# this engages above new .pem file
/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash
```

PS ...  if Citrix is reading this please slurp this up and post on your Citrix workspace install site to help folks like me who had to struggle for hours first time as nowhere is this documented

Comment: Man, thank you _so much_! It's a shame Citrix provides an rpm package and doesn't bother detailing that procedure (or at least nowhere easy to be found).

Comment: On Chrome it doesn't work for me if I export the bottom certificate - I have to export the top one. I'm guessing the server is not the same in my case, but the certificate authority being used is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, downloading the cert itself and copying to `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts` worked. (Made sure to do `chmod 444` on the cert).

Though there should be a more elegant solution since `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundl.trust.crt` has the correct DigiCert already downloaded, so does  `/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem`.

Answer (score 0):

## In three easy steps

```bash
$ cd /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts

$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt

$ /opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/ctx_rehash
```